# Benchmarking AES and RC2 from Openssl - why AES is faster?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I wrote a simple code in pure C to benchmark AES-CBC-256 and RC2-CBC-128 from Openssl. My testing loops look like this:

```
for(i=0; i<tests; i++)
    {
        timer_start();
        for(j=0; j<its; j++)
        {
            RC2_cbc_encrypt(input, enc_out, length, &key, iv_enc, RC2_ENCRYPT);
        }
        stop = timer_stop();
        printf("%f\n",(stop / its) * 1000);
    }

for(i=0; i<tests; i++)
    {
        timer_start();
        for(j=0; j<its; j++)
        {
            AES_cbc_encrypt(input, enc_out, length, &enc_key, iv_enc, AES_ENCRYPT);
        }
        stop = timer_stop();
        printf("%f\n",(stop / its) * 1000);
    }
```

But something wrong is happening, **on every machine I test my code I get strange results, that is, every time AES is faster than RC2**. What could be the problem? I use `getrusage` to measure time (in my timers).

```
AES:
0.010898
0.010471
0.010531

RC2:
0.023261
0.023392
0.023224
```

Comment: Also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3670607/589259), the paragraph just before the last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong. AES is faster because:

- RC2 is rather complex, from a computational perspective.
- AES has been optimized heavily in software, because it is so frequently used.
- Some CPUs have hardware acceleration for AES (e.g. [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) for x86).

Comment: Hmm, and how about 3DES? Should it be faster than RC2 but slower than AES? It seemed strange to me because when I tested it with Openssl, I got `283758` for AES and `205444` for RC2 and was sure that it was me who did the mistake in my code, not the Openssl programmers. Could you be so kind and answer about 3DES and 2 others? Thank you :)

Comment: DES is also rather complex, is difficult to implement in software, and is not hardware-accelerated on most systems. That result sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: So why In Openssl AES in slower than RC2 and in my code is faster than RC2? I tested it with `openssl speed` on the same machine I tested my code

Comment: That sentence doesn't make sense. Besides I think duskwuff correctly answered your question already.

Comment: You're reading the results wrong. The numbers printed by `openssl speed` are the number of iterations it completed per second — higher numbers from this tool mean it's **faster**, not slower.